# Best way to build omplex, conditional binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Consider I have to style basing on two properties:

```
<Label Style={Binding IsEnabled, Convert={x:Static IsEnabledToStyleConverter}} />
```

or

```
<Label Style={Binding IsRequired, Convert={x:Static IsEnabledToStyleConverter}} />
```

TO determine wheter use binding with `IsEnabled` or `IsRequired` is other property - `UseRequried`. How Can is choose between those two bindings basin on `UseRequired`?

I have tried to approaches:

1. Another value converter

I have create own value converter:

```
public class ControlToLableStleConverter: IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value..)
     {
          var myCtrl = (MyControl) value;
          if (myCtrl.UseRequired)
             //return style based on IsRequired property
          else
             //return style based on IsEnabled property
     }
}
```

But the problem is that style is no changing at `IsEnabled` or `IsRequired` changed. Quite obvious, so this solution is out.

2. DataTrigger

I have also created DataTriggers:

```
<Label>
<Label.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseRequired}" Value="True">
       <Setters>
           <Setter Property="Style" Value="{Binding IsRequired ....">
       </Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseRequired}" Value="False">
       <Setters>
           <Setter Property="Style" Value="{Binding IsEnabled ....">
       </Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
</Label.Triggers>
</Label>
```

But `Label.Triggers` can contain only `EventTrigger` elements.. What can i do else?

Comment: If you don't like other provided solutions - use MultiBinding, bind to both properties there and use `IMultiValueConverter` to choose style.

Comment: @Evk seems as the best solution so far ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MultiBinding` in this case, though it might be quite verbose:

```
<Label>
    <Label.Style>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource yourConverter}">
            <Binding Path="IsEnabled" />
            <Binding Path="IsRequired" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

And converter is then:

```
public class StyleConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        // take some caution here, because values can be null or DependencyProperty.UnsetValue in certain cases
        var enabled = (bool) values[0];
        var required = (bool) values[1];
        // choose style
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the triggers within the style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
 <Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseRequired}" Value="True">
       <Setters>
           <!-- Set properties here, not the Style -->
       </Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding UseRequired}" Value="False">
       <Setters>
          <!-- Set properties here, not the Style -->           
       </Setters>
    </DataTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you can't change properties then your best option is to use a [StyleSelector (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I have predefinied styles for IsEnabled and IsRequried. No way to reuse it, do I relly need to copy whole style inside setters?

Comment: In that case you could use a StyleSelector, edited my answer to include that option.

Comment: And how would you apply that style selector to label style?

Answer (score 0):

Put the such logic in the code behind and trigger changes off of `UseRequiered` (or elsewhere) and trigger all property changes such as

```
public bool UseRequiered 
{ 
    get { return _UseRequried; }
    set { _UseRequried = value; DetermineStyle(); }// PropertyChanged in DetermineStyle()

}

public bool IsRequiered
{
    get { return _IsRequiered; }
    set { _IsRequiered = value; DetermineStyle();} // PropertyChanged in DetermineStyle()
}

public bool IsEnabled 
{ 
   get { return _IsEnabled; }
   set { _IsEnabled = value; DetermineStyle(); } // Prop change in DetermineStyle
}

private void DetermineStyle()
{
     _UseRequiered = { Whatever logic is deemed };
     _IsRequired  =  { Whatever logic is deemed };
     _IsEnabled   =  { Whatever logic is deemed };

     OnPropertyChanged("IsRequired");
     OnPropertyChanged("IsEnabled");
     OnPropertyChanged("UseRequiered"); 
}
```

Comment: UseRequried, IsRequired and IsEnabled are dependency properties of parent control. What's more, when I change `IsEnabled` while UseRequired is set to false, It won't update the style.. (because binding is set to `UseRequiered` property)

Comment: @pwas "UseRequried, IsRequired and IsEnabled are dependency properties of parent control." Yes and will be bound to the properties in the VM. How is that different? " It won't update the style.. " see my update. Now once one is changed all can be changed and pushed out.